# I want to create a complex slice in Power BI that will not display the values selected in another slice

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have two slices on a page with the names of cities, the input data in both slices are the same.
It is necessary that there was an opportunity to select an object in the first slice, go to the second slice and select from the list of objects that do not take into account the object selected in the first slice.

I tried to create a copy of the table from which the data for the slices is taken and leave only the column with the data I need. Then use this column to fill in 2 slices, but an error appears in the rest of the charts.

I also tried to write a script in python. Presented a list of data in the form of a dictionary. I created a loop that deleted the data selected in 1 slice and presented the result I needed in the second slice. BUT. If you try to repeat the operation and select another number from 1 slice , it does not restore the previous view of the slice and it turns out ...

https://wampi.ru/image/Ryw97yQ

I will be very grateful for the support provided